# Resize a PictureBox

Tags: c#, image, resize, picturebox

I want to show a Resized Picture in my Picturebox.
The original picture is:
[image]
And the Picture in my form:
[image]

My picturebox size is 500x500px.
My method that I use for the resize:

```
    public static Image ResizePicByWidth(Image sourceImage, double newWidth)
    {
        double sizeFactor = newWidth / sourceImage.Width;
        double newHeigth = sizeFactor * sourceImage.Height;
        Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap((int)newWidth, (int)newHeigth);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(sourceImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeigth));
        }
        return newImage;
    }
```

I call the method with the original picture and the width from the picturebox.
But how can i resize the picture correctly?
I want my Form to show the whole Picture.

Comment: just set the picture's width and height to the value you want.

Comment: You have set a new width but you actually also new to adapt the picturebox to the newHeigth . Or set sizemode to zoom. In that case you don't need to do any resizing at all!

Comment: ur english is bad, sorry.. But the Sizemode is the solution

Comment: _ur english is bad_. Well, I'm sure that is not what you meant ;-) Btw, use of web-speak like 'ur'  instead of 'your' or 'you're' or even 'i' instead of 'I' is strongly discouraged here. SO is not a forum but an archive and every typo is potentially stored for ages..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PictureBox has a SizeMode property.  If you set this to Zoom it will automatically resize the image in it to fit inside it.

Comment: That doesent work.
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4619/ako9gcqp_png.htm

Comment: my fault. i set BackgroundImageLayout to Zoom not the SizeMode. Thanks